# Flex Grow not working with FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying flexGrow with FlatList but it is not working as it works with ListView. The items are getting rendered with minWidth value even if space is there on the screen.
Sample code :

```
class ProductListScreen extends Component {
    render () {
    return (<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'},{key: 'c'},{key: 'd'}, {key: 'e'},{key: 'f'},{key: 'g'}, {key: 'h'},{key: 'i'},{key: 'j'}]}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    />);
    renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return <View style={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    margin: 5,
    minWidth: 154,
    maxWidth: 223,
    height: 304,
    maxHeight:304,
    backgroundColor: '#CCC',
    }}/>;
    }
}
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      list: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      })
```

Comment: This is just happening for ios. Working fine for android.

Comment: ```flexWrap: 'wrap'``` is not supported with the new list components. please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526443/react-native-how-to-wrap-flatlist-items