# React Native - SectionList numColumns support

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns) has `numColumns` support. How to set `numColumns` with [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html)?

Github issue: [SectionList renderItem multi item support #13192](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13192)

Comment: From looking at the Github issue, this has been closed and solved already....so why are you posting this here?

Comment: I believe that issue is not fixed properly, I have posted my answer there too.

Comment: If you only need 2 or 3 sections you can add a FlatList for each one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is my solution to `numColumns` for SectionList. If you have better let me know please.

```
class Example extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    numColumns: PropTypes.number
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    numColumns: 2
  };

  _renderSection = data => <Section {...data} />;

  _renderItem = ({ section, index }) => {
    const { numColumns } = this.props;

    if (index % numColumns !== 0) return null;

    const items = [];

    for (let i = index; i < index + numColumns; i++) {
      if (i >= section.data.length) {
        break;
      }

      items.push(<Item item={section.data[i]} />);
    }

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between"
        }}
      >
        {items}
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SectionList
        sections={dumyData}
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={this._renderSection}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, new bie here, could you please tell that how the 'dumyData' variable looks like?
@pir-shukarullah-shah

Comment: @iDevAmit it should be formatted the same way as a normal SectionList ... similar to the "DATA" array in this example https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-s5FNuiC_s&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=m4dfp0ixvz&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=SectionList&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true

Comment: this solution provides a laggy experience when loading images

Answer (score 10):

Digging this issue up, I came with a solution similar to Pir Shukarullah Shah 's.

I'm using FlatList instead of my regular item, taking into account only the first item in `<SectionList/>'s renderItem` method.

```
 _renderList = ({ section, index }) => {
    if (index !== 0) return null;

    return (
      <FlatList numColumns={columns}
        columnWrapperStyle={styles.container}
        data={section.data}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      />
    )
  }



...
      <SectionList
        renderItem={this._renderList}
        renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
        sections={itemList}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      />
```

Answer (score 8):

I found there is a simple solution. Please try adding the following property to the

```
contentContainerStyle={{
    flexDirection  : 'row',
    justifyContent : 'flex-start',
    alignItems     : 'flex-start',
    flexWrap       : 'wrap'
}}
```

Besides, set and render the Section Header with the Width equal to the SectionList width. Otherwise, the list items will be displayed following the Section Header in row direction.

Comment: this will make this app super laggy when load lots of images

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use FlatList with numColumns prop as the renderItem of SectionList.

```
const data = [ //Notice [[...]] instead of [...] as in the RN docs
    {data: [[...]], title: ...},
    {data: [[...]], title: ...},
    {data: [[...]], title: ...},
]

render () {
    return (
        <SectionList
            renderItem={this._renderSectionListItem}
            renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
            sections={data}
        />
    )
}

renderSectionListItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={item}
            numColumns={3}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but why do you need `FlastList` for 3 items only?

Comment: @PirShukarullahShah The code I posted is just an example for using FlatList to show 3 columns (not 3 items) with some number of items in each list. Choose your own numColums, your own number of items, your own number of sections. There is no limit as far as I know but use removeClippedSubviews to improve performance.

Comment: This is really not recommended since your performance will get very poor with just some (maybe 100) items in FlatList.

Comment: FlatLists perform fine for me for 1000 items. Haven't tried much more than that. With proper use of shouldcomponentupdate and removeClippedSubviews the performance does not seem to deteriorate at all with larger lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const DATA = [
     {
      renderItem: ({ item, index }) => {
          return (<View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between', }}>
          {item.map((elem,index)=>(<View style={{  borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2, minWidth:100 }}>
            <Text>{elem.value}</Text>
          </View>))
          }
          </View>);
       },
      data: [
        [{id:'1', value:'Pizza'}, {id:'2', value:'Burger'}, {id:'3', value:'Onion Rings'}], //this array length will be noOfColumns
        [{id:'4', value:'Risotto'}, {id:'5', value:'French Fries'}, {id:'6', value:'Water'}],
      ],
     },


   <SectionList
      ref={listRef}
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={_keyExtractor}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same logic like Pir Shukarullah Shah. The idea of using flexWrap is not recommended by react and warns to use numColumns prop in flatlist. If anyone has a better solution please add.

```
let items = []

    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        if (index % 2 === 0) {
            items = []
            items.push(<Card cloth={item} index={index} />)
            return (index === clothes[0].data.length - 1) ? <View style={styles.row}>{items}</View> : null
        }

        items.push(<Card cloth={item} index={index} />)
        return (
            <View style={styles.row}>
                {items}
            </View>
        )
    }
```

The section list is :

```
     <SectionList
          sections={clothes}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
          stickyHeaderHiddenOnScroll={true}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
          onEndReached={endReachedHandler}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.25}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: '25%' }}
        />
```

The structure for clothes is:

```
let one = {name: 'Jeans pant'}
let many = Array(10).fill(one) // creating more dummy clothes
let cl = [{data: many, title: 'Cloth'}]
let [clothes, setClothes] = useState(cl)
```

I needed only one section so in cl array I wrote only one object initially if you want to have multiple sections you would need to add to the clothes array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly updated version of Pir Shukarullah Shah accepted answer to show a more functional approach over class approach.

```js
// render a single section.data item 
const itemRenderer = (item) => <Text>{item}</Text>

return (
<SectionList
  sections={listData}
  renderItem={(section, index) => {
    if (index % numCols) { // items are already consumed 
     return null
    }
    // grab all items for the row
    const rowItems = section.data.slice(index, index+numCols)
    // wrap selected items in a "row" View 
    return <View 
      style={{
        flexDirection:"row",
        justifiyContent:"space-between"
      }}
    >{rowItems.map(itemRenderer)}</View>
  }}
/>)
```

Also if you have fixed width items you can calculate numCols dynamically here's an example for a full screen width SectionList:

```js
const itemFixedWidth = 24
const listWidth = useWindowDimensions().width
const numCols   = Math.floor(listWidth / itemFixedWidth)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new user to this site, otherwise I'd just upvote Fong's answer above. Slick, that one.

Just to further clarify the last sentence he wrote.

I used Dimensions.get('window').width on the section header like so:

```
renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <View
              style={{
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
              }}
            >
              <Text>
                {title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
```

Though that method does throw a console warning about using flexWrap...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
const renderItemList: SectionListRenderItem<TicketTypes> = ({
  index,
  section,
}) => {


  if (index % 2 !== 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const item = section.data[index];
  const nextItem = section.data[index + 1];
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 10,
      }}>
      <CardTicket data={item} />
      {nextItem ? <CardTicket data={nextItem} /> : <View style={{flex: 1}} />}
    </View>
  );
};

return (
  <Container>
    <SectionList
      sections={MockTickets}
      keyExtractor={({id}) => id}
      renderItem={renderItemList}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {category}}) => (
        <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'gray', paddingVertical: 10}}>
          {category}
        </Text>
      )}
    />
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).