# How can i achieve this layout using SectionList in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

In the below picture, keywords "Fashion" and "Mobile and Electronics" would be my header title and can be passed to renderSectionHeader of SectionList.

Each subcategory Men's Fashion Women's Fashion etc etc are items that can be passed to renderItem of SectionList.

I think we needs to use FlexWrap to achieve this for Layout but not sure how can i use it along with SectionList.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - SectionList numColumns support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833581/react-native-sectionlist-numcolumns-support)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example. With flatlist having sticky header. Hope this helps

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Left, Body, Right, Title } from "native-base";

const window = Dimensions.get('window');

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

var localizedString;

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

constructor(Props){
    super(Props);
    localizedString = require('./hi.json');
    this.state={
      language:'en',
      stickyHeaderIndices: [],
      dummy: 1,
      data: [
        { name: "Movies", header: true },
        { name: "Interstellar", header: false },
        { name: "Dark Knight", header: false },
        { name: "Pop", header: false },
        { name: "Pulp Fiction", header: false },
        { name: "Burning Train", header: false },
        { name: "Music", header: true },
        { name: "Adams", header: false },
        { name: "Nirvana", header: false },
        { name: "Amrit Maan", header: false },
        { name: "Oye Hoye", header: false },
        { name: "Eminem", header: false },
        { name: "Places", header: true },
        { name: "Jordan", header: false },
        { name: "Punjab", header: false },
        { name: "Ludhiana", header: false },
        { name: "Jamshedpur", header: false },
        { name: "India", header: false },
        { name: "People", header: true },
        { name: "Jazzy", header: false },
        { name: "Appie", header: false },
        { name: "Baby", header: false },
        { name: "Sunil", header: false },
        { name: "Arrow", header: false },
        { name: "Things", header: true },
        { name: "table", header: false },
        { name: "chair", header: false },
        { name: "fan", header: false },
        { name: "cup", header: false },
        { name: "cube", header: false }
      ],
    };

  }


componentWillMount() {
    var arr = [];
    this.state.data.map(obj => {
      if (obj.header) {
        arr.push(this.state.data.indexOf(obj));
      }
    });
    arr.push(0);
    this.setState({
      stickyHeaderIndices: arr
    });
  }

renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (item.header) {
      return (
        <ListItem itemDivider>

          <Body style={{ marginRight: 40, alignItems:'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          </Body>
        </ListItem>
      );
    } else if (!item.header) {
      return (
        <ListItem style={{ marginLeft: 15}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{}} style={{width:'100%'}}>
          <Body>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', width:'90%', marginTop:'5%'}}>
            <View style={{alignItems:'center', borderBottomWidth:1, borderRightWidth:1, paddingRight:'5%', paddingBottom:'2%'}}>
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius:100}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} />
              <Text>Heading</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{alignItems:'center', borderBottomWidth:1, borderRightWidth:1, paddingRight:'5%', paddingLeft:'5%', paddingBottom:'2%'}}>
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius:100}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} />
              <Text>Heading</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{alignItems:'center', borderBottomWidth:1, paddingLeft:'5%', paddingBottom:'2%'}}>
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius:100}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} />
              <Text>Heading</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', width:'90%'}}>
            <View style={{alignItems:'center',  borderRightWidth:1, paddingRight:'5%', paddingTop:'2%'}}>
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius:100}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} />
              <Text>Heading</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{alignItems:'center',  borderRightWidth:1, paddingRight:'5%', paddingLeft:'5%', paddingTop:'2%'}}>
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius:100}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} />
              <Text>Heading</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{alignItems:'center', paddingLeft:'5%', paddingTop:'2%'}}>
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius:100}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}} />
              <Text>Heading</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          </Body>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </ListItem>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ width:'100%', marginBottom:'7%', height:'100%'}}>
              <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                stickyHeaderIndices={this.state.stickyHeaderIndices}
              />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  SectionHeaderStyle:{
    backgroundColor : '#EAEAED',
    padding: 5,
    color: '#000000',
  },

  SectionListItemStyle:{
    fontSize : 15,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#000'
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post a snack.expo.io link. I couldn't get this to work on snack. fixed some errors but All i see is the expo icon on app starting

Comment: Thanks. But i was wondering if it is possible the get this layout with each sub item, (Icon and the Text "Heading") in your example, as a separate class/ component and also maintain the inner border design with it.
I know how i can make sub item a separate component but not sure how i can maintain the inner border of it (border to right of first and second sub item and a border below if there are more sub item in the row below it)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use **flexWrap: 'wrap'** with FlatList or SectionList, so you are probably best off using ScrollView (or some third party grid library).

Answer (score -3):

**[old version]**

this design can be achieved with `FlatList` with property `numColumns`.

```
numColumns={3}
```

Example: https://snack.expo.io/@spencercarli/react-native-flatlist-grid

Reference Link:

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist