# Display list of items in GridView with Grouping

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to implement ***SectionList*** with grid view like using *numColumns* props in **FlatList**

Comment: Probably this would be the solution for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833581/react-native-sectionlist-numcolumns-support please check

Answer (score 0):

This can be the solution for you

```
class Example extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    numColumns: PropTypes.number
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    numColumns: 2
  };

  _renderSection = data => <Section {...data} />;

  _renderItem = ({ section, index }) => {
    const { numColumns } = this.props;

    if (index % numColumns !== 0) return null;

    const items = [];

    for (let i = index; i < index + numColumns; i++) {
      if (i >= section.data.length) {
        break;
      }

      items.push(<Item item={section.data[i]} />);
    }

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between"
        }}
      >
        {items}
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SectionList
        sections={dumyData}
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={this._renderSection}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the [Solution Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833582/1283345)