# React Native FlatList Warning

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

Im trying to implement a FlatList with dynamic item sizes, to be more specific, my items sometimes take the full screen width and sometimes only half of it, thus setting numColumns={2} isn't working, my workaround looks like this:

```
     <FlatList
      ListHeaderComponent={this.header}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      data={data}
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
    />
```

everything is working as expected, the width of an item is applied via item.width. However the issue is that every time it's rendering the list, im getting this log warning:

```
Warning: `flexWrap: `wrap`` is not supported with the `VirtualizedList` components.Consider using `numColumns` with `FlatList` instead.
```

Does anybody know how this is affecting the performance of the list and if it has an affect, how I can improve my code ?

This is how I would like it to look like:

[image: Example]

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526443/react-native-how-to-wrap-flatlist-items)

Comment: This is not working

Comment: can you please share your code on expo snack?

Comment: Yes I made a replica with all the unnecessary stuff removed: https://snack.expo.io/SJxjkMLM_4

Answer (score 0):

to fix numColumns={2} you have to set with it  horizontal={false}
so it becomes

```
      <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={this.header}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        data={data}
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={2} 
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
       />
```

Comment: When using numColums it renders Items outside of the screen, it allways placing 2 items next to each other however I would like to have items that take the full screen width